# How can I save randomly generated train and test datasets?

Tags: r

I am using a for loop to generate 100 different train and test sets.

What I want to do now, is to save these 100 different train and test sets in order to be able to have a look at e.g. where iteration was 17.

This code shows my program with the for loop and the division into train and test set:

```
result_df<-matrix(ncol=3,nrow=100)
colnames(result_df)<-c("Acc","Sens","Spec")

for (g in 1:100 )
{

  # Divide into Train and test set
  smp_size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(mydata1))
  train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mydata1)), size = smp_size)
  train <- mydata1[train_ind, ]
  test <- mydata1[-train_ind, ]

  REST OF MY CODE




  # Calculate some statistics

  overall <- cm$overall
  overall.accuracy <- format(overall['Accuracy'] * 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
  overall.sensitivity <- format(cm$byClass['Sensitivity']* 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
  overall.specificity <- format(cm$byClass['Specificity']* 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)

  result_df[g,1] <- overall.accuracy
  result_df[g,2] <- overall.sensitivity
  result_df[g,3] <- overall.specificity

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following, for example, saving each test and train sets as elements in a list:

```
result_df<-matrix(ncol=3,nrow=100)
colnames(result_df)<-c("Acc","Sens","Spec")
testlist <- list()
trainlist <- list()
for (g in 1:100 )
{
  # Divide into Train and test set
  smp_size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(mydata1))
  train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mydata1)), size = smp_size)
  train <- mydata1[train_ind, ]
  test <- mydata1[-train_ind, ]
  trainlist[[g]] <- train
  testlist[[g]] <- test
  }
```

---

**EDIT**
To retrieve the 7th element of these lists you could use `trainlist[[7]]`

Comment: Thanks gpier for your answer! I ran your code and had a look at the train list. How can I select, let's say the 7th iteration with all columns?

Comment: Welcome! see edits, if ok for you please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: This gives me only the 7th element (e.g. date)...How can I get the entrie 7th iteration with all my columns (every trainset has 5 columns)?

Answer (score 1):

You can save those in csv file by using the following method

```
write.csv(train, file = paste0("train-", Sys.time(), ".csv", sep=""))
write.csv(test, file = paste0("test-", Sys.time(), ".csv", sep=""))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If I save it like this, I would only receive one train and one test set...saying, that I would overwrite the other randomly generated datasets. Is there a way I can save it in R?

Comment: Edited to using timestamp in the file name

Comment: I ran your answer with the specific location of where to save (`file = O:\\""train.csv"`, unfortunately I receive an error message...it seems that R can't find this location. Without the `file=...` it runs perfectly, but I don't know where the csv file has been saved :/

Comment: Maybe it’s either a permission issue or wrong format on the file path or it is not inside the working directory

Comment: I change the working directory, but I can't find the files anywhere

Comment: did you set it with setwd(“H:/foo”) ?

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a function and do a `lapply()`:

```
result_df <- matrix(ncol=3, nrow=100)
colnames(result_df)<-c("Acc", "Sens", "Spec")

SIMg <- function(g) {

  # Divide into Train and test set
  smp_size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(mydata1))
  train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mydata1)), size = smp_size)
  train <- mydata1[train_ind, ]
  test <- mydata1[-train_ind, ]

  REST OF THE CODE

  return(list(train=train, test=test, ...))
}
L <- lapply(1:100, SIMg)
```

The resulting list `L` has 100 elements, each element is a list containing the two dataframes and your results for one simulation run.
To get separate lists `trainlist` and `testlist` you can do:

```
trainlist <- lallpy(L, '[[', "train")
testlist  <- lallpy(L, '[[', "test")
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to save the row indexes of your partitions, rather than saving all the datasets, and then select the rows indexes for the iteration you're interested in.

The caret package has a function called createDataPartition, which will do this for you:

```
library(caret)

df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(100), col2 = rnorm(100))

# create 100 partitions
train.idxs <- createDataPartition(1:nrow(df), times = 100, p = 0.8)

for(i in 1:length(train.idxs)) {
# create train and test sets 
idx <- train.idxs[[i]]
train.df <- df[idx, ]
test.df <- df[-idx, ]

# calculate statistics ...

result_df[i,1] <- overall.accuracy
result_df[i,2] <- overall.sensitivity
result_df[i,3] <- overall.specificity
}

# check the datasets for the nth partition
# train set
df[train.idxs[[n]], ]

# test set
df[-train.idxs[[n]], ]
```

Comment: This seems like a nice solution! The only thing which is bugging me, is that I use the for loop not only to divide into train and test set, but also to calculate some statistics...please see my edits.

Comment: You could create the partitions outside of the loop, then use the loop to iterate through the elements in the partitions list

Comment: I've not tested it, but I think this should do what you need